# UTF 8 decoding issue for json(using google gson) string

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, utf-8, gson

I have Spring controller method which returns json string using Google.Gson. Problem is, my json string has UTF-8 content and when I access url from browser then it's showing the data in encoded format.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/getLocations.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLocations(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().serializeNulls().create();
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    Set<Locations> locs = channelService.getLocations();
    String json = gson.toJson(locs);        
    return json;
}
```

When I access getLocations.json from browser address bar below is what I get :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"\u0026#3248;\u0026#3262;\u0026#3255;\u0026#3277;\u0026#3231;\u0026#3277;\u0026#3248;\u0026#3264;\u0026#3247;"},{"id":2,"name":"Districts"}]
```

Any Idea where I am going worng? Or how can I decode the data back?

Comment: try removing `charset=utf-8`

Comment: @ankur-singhal, it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
var res = uri_enc + "<br>" + uri_dec; 


http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab     // Encoded URI
http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab                            // Decoded URI
```

after decoding , try to parse json

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
```